# Scraping data using Nokogiri

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, web-scraping, nokogiri

I am trying to scrape data using Nokogiri.  The code I am trying to access is:

```
<div class="main-header">
    <span>Make More Money</span>
</div>
```

I want to get the text "Make More Money", only.  Here is my code:

```
url = 'xyz.com'
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url)) 
doc.at_css('main-header span').text
```

Using this I am getting a `NilClass` error.  What do I need to do to fix this?

Comment: There's something wrong with your CSS selector. I suspect that the first element is selected by `div#main-header` rather than just `main-header`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `.` for the class `main-header` is missing. It should be

```
doc.at_css('.main-header span').text
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can this be used when the class in the HTML element is added by JavaScript dynamically

Comment: No, Nokogiri does not execute javascript. Some alternatives can be found, like in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11494994/is-it-possible-to-plug-a-javascript-engine-with-ruby-and-nokogiri

Comment: I recommend Capybara and Poltergeist!